# Problemas com IONIC 2 em vários aspectos

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

A grande pergunta é: O que houve com o IONIC depois das atualizaçoes.

A alguns meses atrás comecei um projeto com IONIC 2 para um cliente. Devido a alguns contratempos meus e por parte também do cliente, o projeto deu uma parada. Contudo, voltamos agora para ativa e me deparo com vários comandos que não funcionam mais. Há mais de 3 dias estou tendo problemas com configurações e só agora consegui fazer rodar o app no meu smartphone com erros.

Bom, não estou aqui pra chorar kk então lá vai minhas dúvidas:

**Primeiro problema** o **BrowserTab**, plugin nativo do IONIC, não funciona mais. Uma vez já executado o código anteriormente com sucesso, só fiz baixar do repositório e rodei novamente no meu smartphone, porém resulta em nada. Simplesmente parou de funcionar.  Tentei debugar com o comando `cordova run android --livereload --device`, mas *o terminal fecha sempre que o app abre no meu celular* **(segundo problema)**, sendo impossível obter alguma mensagem de erro para poder identificar a causa. Segue abaixo o código que não funciona mais.

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
public navParams: NavParams,
private browserTab: BrowserTab) {}

openPage(option) {
switch (option) {
  case 0:
      this.browserTab.openUrl("https://pag.ae/bkjsxHd");
    break;

  case 1:
      this.browserTab.openUrl("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=8RV2DK95S29LJ");
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

}

Já realizei o **npm install**, **já instalei o browserTab** plugin seguindo o seguinte link [Documentação para o browserTab](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser-tab/).
Executo o LiveReload conforme a documentação [aqui](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/) que não é live coisa nenhuma rsrs.

Enfim, estou perdido. Já pesquisei bastante e sem resultado. A mais de 3 dias improdutivos sem saber mais oq fazer.

Bom, segue abaixo também minhas dependências para análise:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "com.semadpb.www: An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-browsertab": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
```

Bom, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda. Pois como trabalhar com IONIC agora se seguindo a própria documentação não está produzindo sucesso. No aguardo...

Comment: Vc rodou com ionic serve para rodar no browser e viu se aparece algo no console? Eu venho acompanhando o Ionic desde a versão 2 até a atual e tive dificuldades no começo, mas agora a cada atualização não tenho encontrado problemas quando eu sigo a informações no https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases . A maior alteração que tive que fazer foi quando mudou da versão 2.3.0 para a versão 3.0.0 que usa angular 4. Como não sei a versão que vc usava antes aconselho a atualizar node, npm, ionic e cordova, começar um projeto novo do zero e ir adicionando suas páginas e ir verificando cada erro.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Rodei usando o ionic serve sim e o BrowserTab também não funciona. Pesquisando agora pela manhã, consegui debugar o app rodando diretamente pelo celular através de uma ferramenta do google chrome://inspect/#devices (fica a dica). E ao clicar no botão para rodar o BrowserTab ele indica o seguinte erro: tried calling BrowserTab.openUrl, but the BrowserTab plugin is not installed.Install the BrowserTab plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-browsertab'. Será q esqueci algum comando? Rodei o add platform, build e run normalmente. Desde já agradeço mais uma vez!

Comment: Uma observação. Como já dito antes, instalei o browserTab conforme documentação e já realizei a verificação e o mesmo se encontra importado nos providers no app.module.ts. Não sei que passo esqueci.

Comment: executa ionic cordova plugin list e vê se ele aparece na lista de plugins.

Comment: Vlw @AndréVicente pela ajuda. Entendi o problema e resolvi. Vou explicar na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, depois de muito tentar descobri o pq dos problemas:

1 - O BrowserTab tem q ser instalado com o NPM e com o CORDOVA. Como eu só tinha baixado o projeto e só rodado npm install, faltou instalar o plugin através do cordova antes de buildar a plataforma e gerar o apk. Por conta disso não funcionava. (Porém, era estranho pois o apk q já tinha gerado uma vez antes (há uns dois meses quando comecei o app), tbm tinha parado de funcionar no meu celular sem eu ter mexido. Mas enfim, voltou a funcionar).

2 - O livereload me parece q tem realmente alguns bugs, portanto, basta vc instalar com o `cordova run android/ios --device` e depois usar uma ferramenta do google chrome q é a `chrome://inspect/#devices`, basta o aparelho estar conectado via cabo usb. (fonte onde achei a dica: [aqui](http://ramonsilva.net/boas-praticas/depuracao-de-aplicativos-hibridos-no-aparelho/)).

Bom, é isso. Espero ajudar a outros com o mesmo problema, se existirem.